# How to set intent in a watson conversation dialog

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

This is about Watson Conversation Dialogs

I have an app that sends some webhook information which has some pre-defined Watson Intent. How can I jump directly to the nodes that deals with that intent?

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to do this.

1. You can use a trained question/keyword and that should 100% match.
2. If you preload the `intents` object, then it will treat that as the actual intent.

Comment: To clarify 2. - when doing a request to Watson conversation service you can send your intents as a part of the input to conversation service, these can be then worked with in the Watson Conversation dialog.